# How to make the all Components to be responsive

Tags: react-native, react-native-ios

```
import {Dimensions} from 'react-native'

var {height, width} = Dimensions.get('window');

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  HeddingStyle:{
    fontSize: (width*0.02)
  }
})
```

**But this is not working properly by using Dimensions**

Comment: What is happening and what should happen?

Comment: I want to make my layout to be responsive to all screen sizes  for screen size of  720×1280  its working fine but for 480×800 its not aligned and font size is not responsive

Answer (score 2):

Use them separated, like this:

```
const SCREEN_WIDTH = Dimensions.get('window').width;
const SCREEN_HEIGHT = Dimensions.get('window').height;
```

Then on your styles you can do stuff like this:

```
inputContainer: {
  width: SCREEN_WIDTH - 50,
}
```

Or in your case:

```
HeddingStyle:{
  fontSize: SCREEN_WIDTH * 0.02,
}
```